# how to get the query based on this requirement？

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

hello may i know the sql query based on the link images's requirement? can everyone give me the answers?

can everyone check mine answers correct
?

```
select 
products.name, 
products.total, 
invoiceLine.sum(quantity), 
invoiceLine.sellingprice*invoiceLine.quantity AS total_price 
from products,invoiceLine,invoice 
where products.prodCode=invoiceLine.prodCode and 
invoice.invoiceDate>= add_months(sysdate, -6)
ORDER BY quantity DESC;
```

Comment: *i want to compare to mine aswer* If so then you must provide your solution accompanied by **complete and detailed logic explanation**.

Comment: Do not post facts as comments, add them into the question text (link "Edit" under it).

Comment: can you help me check have any problem on mine query?akina

Comment: Update your question with the SQL, don’t put relevant information in comments. What issue/question do you have about your SQL? You need to be more specific than “is my SQL correct?”. Also, you should be using ANSI SQL join syntax - the syntax you’ve used hasn’t been good practice for 30+ years

Comment: ok modified....

Comment: OK - but you haven't changed the join syntax and you haven't actually asked a specific question about your SQL. BTW your syntax for using SUM is wrong

Comment: Also your date logic is not aligned to what the question asks and your order by also doesn't align with the question either

Comment: NickW can you give me the proper answer ? i a bit dont understand

Answer (score 0):

As this is obviously a homework/tutorial question I won't just give you the answer - as that way you won't learn anything - but I will give you some more detailed help. You will still need to do your own research/investigation to be able to write the correct answer yourself:

**ANSI JOIN SYNTAX:**

```
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL2
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T2.COL1 = T3.COL2
...
```

**SUM**

SUM function goes round the full column name e.g.

```
sum(invoiceLine.quantity)
```

not

```
invoiceLine.sum(quantity)
```

When using an aggregate function (SUM, COUNT, AVG, etc.) all the columns in your SELECT statement, that don't use aggreagete functions, need to be included in a GROUP BY clause

**DATE**

The question asks for records in the "first 3 months of 2021"; your code is selecting records in the past 6 months

**SORT**

The question ask you to sort by the total units sold; you are sorting by "quantity" which is the individual quantity for each record, not total units sold

Comment: hi thanks NickW for the part of is not true for sum the quantity?

Comment: for the sort why sum aggregate cannot sum the total units sold?